# iTunes 12: Is there a way to increase album art size in the Album View

Tags: itunes, album-art

I remember in earlier versions of iTunes it was possible to increase the size of album artwork in the Album View via a slider - so, for example, I could have fewer albums with large cover art per row or more albums per row, but with tiny cover art.

However, I can't find this function anymore in iTunes 12. Does anyone know how to do this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question but no solution.

Someone somewhere advised an app: Swinian. It has the slider for changing the artwork. Very nice app. one month free trial.

Other (obvious)workaround is changing the screen resolution. I use an app Switchres.Easy and fast but ofcourse it changes the resolution everywhere and not just iTunes album view.

It works but not ideal or perfect.